# I want to list all countries in my dropdownlist, where can i get that web service?

Tags: asp.net

I want to list all the countries in my dropdown list. where can i get all the names?
from service right? How to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Get the [ISO 3166 country list](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm); this is the world's official country list complete with official names and country codes. You can even get it in [XML](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm) format and regular [updates](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/updates_on_iso_3166.htm) are available.

Comment: Maybe set a cron job to update your local list every month with this data. It's all too easy to assume things like country lists don't ever change, but it's worth putting a little bit of extra effort in to make sure it updates automatically, IMHO.

Comment: how about internationalization (fr, es, etc)? is there a free alternative? (a really list that could be seen)

Comment: Let's say a country ceases to exist. What do you do with address data currently linked to that country? It's hard to assign this to a new country, as that would require checking what side of the new border (if any) the address was located....

Answer (score 3):

Web Service?
Do you really consider calling Web Service each time just to get a static list of countries? This list is pretty static and does not change even each year.
I would suggest to go and copy the list from any web site that has it.
After that you could store it in your Database or somewhere else or even fix code it ( given that you are using it only on one place ).

Comment: who told you that the list should be loaded at **every** page reload?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, for the *English* country names list

http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx

If anyone has an internationalized example would be very good to post here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a broken link  (Empty response)